# Why this problem of this function? when I click on the a tag the picture appear and disappear immediately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

Where did I do something wrong.what is the problem with this piece of code. when I click on the a tag the picture appear and disappear in a second. I don't know how to work it out.

```
<div id="Slideshow">

            <span id="prev"></span>
            <span id="next"></span>

            <div id="Slideshow-images">
                <a class="Slideshow-item" href=""><img src="images/Slideshow-image1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="Slideshow-item" href=""><img src="images/Slideshow-image2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="Slideshow-item" href=""><img src="images/Slideshow-image3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="Slideshow-item" href=""><img src="images/Slideshow-image4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="Slideshow-item" href=""><img src="images/Slideshow-image5.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div id="Slideshow-Navigator">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="Yekan sm-size" href="" onclick="goToSlide(2);">محصولات کالای خواب </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button>Start First Slider</button>

<script>
    var SlideshowTag = $('#Slideshow');
    var SlideshowItems = SlideshowTag.find('.Slideshow-item');
    var itemsNum = SlideshowItems.length;
    var nextSlide = 1;

    function first_Slider() {
        if(nextSlide > itemsNum){
            nextSlide = 1;
        }
        if(nextSlide < 1){
            nextSlide = itemsNum;
        }
        SlideshowItems.hide();
        SlideshowItems.eq(nextSlide-1).fadeIn(100);
        nextSlide++;
    }

function goToSlide(index){
        nextSlide=index;
        first_Slider();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for us to tell. Please make an interactive example by reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the help center and update your question.

Comment: Change `href=""` to `href="#"` so the page doesn't reload

Comment: Also, for future reference, watch your browser's debugging network tab - you'll see the page reloading (possibly also the console "navigated to"

Comment: @emiel-zuurbier I will do that. thank your for the reference link.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you a lot for your answer and your tips, for sure I will do that. it fixed my problem.